# Using firebase cloud function to copy all documents from a master collection in Firestore to new sub-collection

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a master collection in firestore with a couple hundred documents (which will grow to a few thousand in a couple of months).

I have a use case, where every time a new user document is created in /users/ collection, I want all the documents from the master to be copied over to /users/{userId}/.

To achieve this, I have created a firebase cloud function as below:

```
// setup for new user
exports.setupCollectionForUser = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}')
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const userId = context.params.userId;

    db.collection('master').get().then(snapshot => {

      if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log('no docs found');
        return;
      }

      snapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

        return db.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('slave').doc(doc.get('uid')).set(doc.data());
      });
    });
 });
```

This works, the only problem is, it takes forever (~3-5 mins) for only about 200 documents. This has been such a bummer because a lot depends on how fast these documents get copied over. I was hoping this to be not more than a few seconds at max. Also, the documents show up altogether and not as they are written, or at least they seem that way.

Am I doing anything wrong? Why should it take so long?

Is there a way I can break this operation into multiple reads and writes so that I can guarantee a minimum documents in a few seconds and not wait until all of them are copied over?

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaking, by correctly managing the parallel writes with [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and returning the Promises chain it should normally improve the speed.

Try to adapt your code as follows:

```
exports.setupCollectionForUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        const userId = context.params.userId;

        return db.collection('master').get().then(snapshot => {  

            if (snapshot.empty) {
                console.log('no docs found');
                return null;
            } else {

                const promises = [];
                const slaveRef = db.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('slave');
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {

                      promises.push(slaveRef.doc(doc.get('uid')).set(doc.data()))

                });

                return Promise.all(promises);

            }

        });

    });
```

---

I would suggest you watch the 3 videos about "JavaScript Promises" from the [Firebase video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series/) which explain why it is key to return a Promise or a value in a background triggered Cloud Function.

---

Note also, that if you are sure you have less than 500 documents to save in the `slave` collection, you could use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes). (You could use it for more than 500 docs but then you would have to manage different batches of batched write...)